# Unexplained SOLR query

Tags: sxa, solr, indexing, sxa-search

I'm using Sitecore instance 9.1, Solr 7.2.1, and SXA 1.8.

I was checking "Search" logs and found below ERROR entry.

```
5012 12:49:26 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=((query:(self) AND _path:(71a2055091824473b4739f0f0371f665)) AND _language:(en))&rows=100&fl=_group,_uniqueid,_datasource&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_sxa_master_index)&wt=xml

5012 12:49:26 ERROR Solr Error : ["undefined field query"] - Query attempted: [((query:(self) AND _path:(71a2055091824473b4739f0f0371f665)) AND _language:(en))]
```

[image]

The Id mentioned in the ERROR belongs to site node.

[image]

I'm including scopes for reference as well :

[image]

```
+template:{AAD056AF-2DFA-4ABE-888D-1C586BACC8B5};+location:{C9AF7803-0B7B-4338-BD13-FE79BFAF1087};sort:creationdate[desc]

+location:{2BACB8D2-D52E-438D-B3AE-19A2EE2F52B4};template:{bedc2cd6-2e99-4a40-865a-f6ac0cd04dc4};template:{8bd101e0-2139-453d-8ff9-4ff883f64c29};template:{212ef82c-d5ac-47d9-ab51-10df39053775}

+template:{AAD056AF-2DFA-4ABE-888D-1C586BACC8B5};+location:{A5EA5A22-1A64-4434-B4F8-5387EDC04B26};sort:creationdate[desc]
```

I understand why this query is failing. BUT, I don't know which component is firing this query, in order for me to edit or stop.

Any Clues ??

Comment: Thanks for adding details. Now please add the remaining missing details about the problem you are trying to solve, thereby giving the search engines a reason to find your post and show it to other users with the same problem.

Comment: I've added further elaboration ... will this allow my question to be open again ?

Comment: We can give it a go. I don't think there is really enough information here but let's see.

Comment: looks like you are trying to utilizing pretty heavy Sitecore queries to get the datasource for the rendering or for something else. I would suggest you first check the datasource for the items which are using `71a2055091824473b4739f0f0371f665` as a path.

Comment: Can you include what the ScopeQuery looks like in SXA? The details about what you originally setup will be helpful.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat, I've hundreds of items and renderings, how can I query for that ?

Comment: @MichaelWest, I've added more elaboration ..